# In Linux what happens if 1000 files in a directory are moved to another location while another 300 files were added to the source directory?

Tags: linux, filesystems, operating-systems

In Linux what happens if 1000 files in a directory are moved to another location and another 300 files were added to the source directory while original 1000 files were being moved. Will the destination end up being 1300 files? or will there be 300 files remaining in the source folder.

Comment: This is not a direct answer, which seems to be well provided by @Eugene-Rieck. But, you might find it interesting/userful to read about Race Conditions (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition ). They seem to be relevant to your question. In effect, if the specific commands you use to do the moving and adding of files create a race condition, then unusual things will happen.

Comment: @user02814: The problem with race conditions is that unusual things *might* happen. When you're looking for them or writing tests, they usually don't happen. When you're putting code in production, they will surely happen. :)

Comment: As an anecdotal case, I was moving a *directory* (`mv dir/ other/`) during which I added files to it. At the end of the move the directory was deleted and the uncopied files disappeared with it.

Comment: To my above comment: across filesystems, that is.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

This depends on which tools you use: Let's check a few cases:

If you run something along the lines of `mv /path/to/source/* /path/to/dest/` int a shell, you will end up with the original 1000 files being moved, the new 300 being untouched. This comes from the fact, that the shell will expand the `*` before starting the move operation, so when the move is in progress, the list is already fixed.

If you use Nautilus (and other GUI friends), you will end up the same way: It will run the move operation based on which files were selected - this doesn't change when new files show up.

If you use your own program using syscalls along the line of loop over `glob` and only **one** `mv` until `glob` stays empty, you will end up with all 1300 files in the new directory. This is because every new `glob` will pick up the new files, that have showed up in the meantime.

Comment: What happens if you opendir() the source, then loop over readdir() or getdents()?

Comment: If you loop only once, then it won't change.

Comment: Is that true for all filesystems, and regardless of the amount of files? I assumed the kernel generally returns live results through readdir(), and doesn't pre-cache them or anything.

Comment: The result-set of an `opendir()` is stable according to POSIX. A quick test with PHP's `opendir()` confirms that (but I tested only ext4).

Comment: Turns out the result set of `opendir()` must be cached, as there is a limit on the number of returned values. This can't be true on a dynamic directory handle.

Comment: @grawity: Not well defined.

Comment: @grawity: POSIX says: _If a file is removed from or added to the directory after the most recent call to opendir() or rewinddir(), whether a subsequent call to readdir() returns an entry for that file is unspecified._ Also, NFS may put some restrictions on what is implementable, IIRC it complicates implementation of `telldir()/seekdir()`

Comment: @grawity: tangentially related: https://lwn.net/Articles/544520/

Comment: minor nitpicking thought: couldn't the expansion take so long that the 300 files - or some of them - are already copied over even though copying was triggered slightly after the moving, e.g. in a script ?

Comment: What happens if the dir contains something like a billion files where the expanding of the wildcard takes a non-insignificant amount of time and the 300 files are moved there while this expanding takes place?

Comment: @d-b With more than say 100 000 files, the expanded command line will exceed the maximum command length limit (ARG_MAX, usually a few MiB) and the `mv` will fail to execute.

Comment: @d-b If files are added or removed _while expanding takes place_, then the readdir discussion applies (because that's how the expansion is done too).

Comment: A bit more digging shows, that the resultset is stable and not stable - in Linux `readdir()` will populate a buffer of 32K a time and keep this stable - if the resultset exceeds 32K, the next 32K block is loaded, which is an unstable operation, and then kept stable until exhausted. So for many thousands of files things looks different. You can use `getdents()` with a bigger buffer size than 32K instead of "pure" `readdir()`to care for the "many files" case

Comment: What's funny is that while this approach seems very sensible, it is in fact not. That's because the likelihood of the directory contents changing mid-operation goes up as the number of files to process or copy (and thus time needed) increases. So, what looks like a sensible implementation is actually quite stupid because it wastes resources for cases where there isn't a problem to start with (copying 1-2 files, or maybe 20 of them), and _presses_ the problem where it is likely to occur (copying 20,000 files). Still, good catch on your side :-)

Comment: @Damon I beg to differ: Reading a directory **from disk** is a very expensive operation - a 32K buffer takes care of between 500 and 1000 files with a single disk read, which seems perfect for the vast majority of `readdir()` operations used. Directories with more than 1000 files are rather exotic, and using `getdents()` with a bigger buffer is a reasonable burden for those.

Comment: @EugenRieck since your comment and Ninjalj's are in contradiction; could you provide your reference that posix says that it's stable?

Comment: I had a bookmark of the same article, that Ninjalj quoted and it contains a link to https://lwn.net/Articles/544846/ (*The spec allows the application to read one filename a week and still be guaranteed to see all files that existed when it started the read with no duplicates.*). This was of course made obsolete by my digging deeper, which showed stability only in buffer-sized chunks.

Comment: "you will end up with the original 1000 files being moved, the new 300 being untouched" I just tested this by moving 100 000 from FS A to FS B while moving another 10 000 files from a different location in FS to where those 100 000 files are. The 10 000 files just vanished.

Comment: @UTF-8 This has nothing to do with this question: You either hit a bug or did somethin wrong - files should NEVER just vanish.

Comment: @EugenRieck I suppose I forgot about the `/*`. But without, there really seems to be a bug. I just reproduced my previous result and documented exactly what I did in this video: https://youtu.be/TvJYf_H6-O8 Edit: It will take a few minutes for this video to appear in any reasonable resolution where you can actually see what I'm doing. YT seems to be slow. It's a 4K video, not a 360p one. Don't worry. ;) Do you think it's a bug I should file or did I do something wrong?

Comment: @UTF-8 That's a completely different story! You moved the directory, not the files it contains! That's a single move operation, not thousands of them.

Comment: @EugenRieck Yes, I know. That's why I stated that I was wrong. I did not exactly do what was asked about in the question. However, do you think this is a bug in `mv`?

Answer (score 8):

When you tell the system to move all the files from a directory, it lists all the files and then starts moving them. If new files appear in the directory, they aren't added to the list of files to move, so they'll remain in the original location.

You can, of course, program a way of moving files different to `mv` which will periodically check for new files in the source directory.

Comment: like say xargs mv?

Answer (score 8):

The kernel itself can't be "in the middle" of a "move 1000 files" operation.  You need to be much more specific about what operation you're proposing.

One thread can only move one file at a time with the [`rename(*oldpath, const char *newpath)` or `renameat` system calls](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/rename.2.html) (and only within the same filesystem<sup>1</sup>).  Or Linux `renameat2` which has flags like `RENAME_EXCHANGE` to atomically exchange two pathnames, or `RENAME_NOREPLACE` to *not* replace the destination if it exists.  (e.g. allowing a `mv -i` implementation that avoids the race condition of `stat` and then `rename`, which would still overwrite a file created after `stat`. 
 [`link`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/link.2.html) + `unlink` could also solve that, because `link` fails if the new name exists.)

**But each of these system calls only renames a single directory entry per system call**.  Using POSIX `renameat` with `olddirfd` and `newdirfd` (opened with `open(O_DIRECTORY)`) would allow you to keep looping over files in a directory even if the source or destination directory *itself* had been renamed.  (Using relative paths could also allow that with regular `rename()`.)

Anyway, as the other answers say, most programs that use the rename system call will figure out a list of filenames before doing the first `rename`.  (Usually using the [`readdir(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html) POSIX library function as a wrapper for platform-specific system calls like Linux [`getdents`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getdents.2.html)).

But if you're talking about `find -exec ... {} \;` to run one command per file, or the more efficient `-exec {} +` with so many files that they don't fit on one command line, then you can certainly have renames happening while still scanning.  e.g.

```
find . -name '*.txt' -exec mv -t ../txtfiles {} \;   # Intentionally inefficient
```

If you created some new `.txt` files while this was running, you *might* see some of them in `../txtfiles`.  But internally `find(1)` will have used `open(O_DIRECTORY)` and `getdents` on `.`.

**If one system call was enough to return *all* the directory entries in `.`** (which find will loop over one at a time, only making further system calls if needed for `-type` or to recurse, or fork+exec on a match), then the list is a snapshot of the directory entries at one point in time.  Further changes to the directory can't affect what `find` does, because it already has a copy of the directory listing what it will loop over.  (Probably it internally uses `readdir(3)`, which returns one entry at a time, but inside glibc we know from using `strace find .` that it makes a `getdents64` system call with a buffer size of `count=32768` entries.)

But if the directory is huge and/or the kernel doesn't fill `find`'s buffer, it will have to make a 2nd getdents system call after looping over what it got the first time.  So it could maybe see new entries after doing some renames.

But see discussion in comments under other answers: the kernel might have snapshotted for us, because (I think) getdents isn't allowed to return the same filename twice.  Different filesystems use different sorting / indexing mechanisms for making access to an entry in a huge directory more efficient than a linear search.  So adding or removing a directory might possibly have other effects on the order of the remaining entries.  Hmm, probably it's more likely that filesystems keep a stable order, and just update an actual index (like the EXT4 `dir_index` feature), so a directory FD's position can just be a directory entry to resume from?  I really don't know how the `telldir(3)` library interface maps onto `lseek`, or if that's purely a user-space thing for looping over the buffer obtained by user-space.  But multiple `getdents` can be needed to get all the entries from a huge directory, so even if seeking isn't supported, the kernel needs to be able to record a current position.

---

**Footnote 1:**

To "move" between filesystems, it's up to user-space to copy and unlink.  (e.g. with `open` and either `read+write`, `mmap+write` or [`sendfile(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sendfile.2.html) or [`copy_file_range(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/copy_file_range.2.html), the latter two totally avoiding bouncing the file data through user-space.)